# Why can't we add ozone to the ozone layer?

Tags: ozone

So that it becomes the ozone layer?

Comment: Check how ozone is destroyed by free radical *chain reactions* by chlorine containing compounds. The agents which destroy ozone, keep on destroying more and more ozone molecules.

Comment: Suppose we solve this problem, then what? The real problem always is "where is the money". See, Earth is YUGE (about as big as Donald Trump's ego, only bigger). You'll need all the money in the world, and then some. Sad!

Comment: This is a chemist's version of "if you're homeless, just buy a house" meme.

Comment: @IvanNeretin the earth IS kinda YUGE, but the atmosphere is really just a thin little sleeve of gas separating us from the vacuum... It is a sham! We need a bigger wall!

Comment: Ozone is generated at the much faster rate ( by UV C ) that we could deploy artificially. (Using Hg UV lamp, you can sniff ozone yourself ).  And at the same time destroyed by compounds with significant [Ozone depletion potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_depletion_potential).

Comment: @StianYttervik Not so thin - it has mass of the 10 m thick water layer.

Comment: @Poutnik while the earth has a ~6.370.000 m thick layer of water, stone and iron. In comparison it is quite slim.

Comment: @StianYttervik In context of required  selective passage of EM radiation, it is not slim.

Answer (score 4):

### The ozone layer is stabilized and recovering on it's own.

There is not much reason TO add ozone to it, though I guess we could - at great expense either inject or create it in situ.

The reason it was a problem in the 80s was the widespread use and release of certain gases to the atmosphere. These gases had a terminating effect on the ozone radical mechanism, that is they end the chain reaction. The gases that were worst were refrigerator gases, used for all kinds of heat exchange pumping. Freon, for instance. It was subsequently capped and banned. It is now only used sparingly, it is to my knowledge in most developed countries illegal to use it IF a different type can suffice.

Following that the release of such gases are only a fraction of what they were and the half lifes of these gases in the atmosphere has been passed several times, and the ozone layer has stabilized and is recovering.

That being said, good old Freon was a fantastic heat exchange gas. My office still has a fridge from the 60s that just keeps on running.

Comment: I wasn't asking what caused the ozone layer to be what it is today, so I guess your answer caused confusion and got this question closed. Sigh.

Comment: @NealConroy or maybe you can edit your question to clarify your doubts. As it stands, your question is not clear, hence it's closed.

Comment: @NealConroy Questions get closed for the question itself.  Answers are being dealt independently. //  Always include enough context and background of your question to make the question clear,  preventing  misunderstanding and clarification. // When you ask, it is expected you have thoroughly searched and thought about the topic, providing explicit summary of partial answers/ideas/thoughts you have got until then. It is quite common requirement across all StackExchange sites.

Comment: I think my question is ambiguous, and that should matter the most. I don't know of how it can be interpreted another way.

Comment: @NealConroy Your question now contains 3 questions which are different from each other, and the title is different from the body. You are also adding one anecdotal and non-relevant  statement. If you cannot see how the question is ambiguous then it is hard to help you.

Comment: Chlorofluorocarbons are worth looking at. In summary, a chlorine free radical is constantly regenerated and constantly took out ozone molecules. That is why the ozone layer was depleting quickly.

Comment: Yes, I had more than 1 question. And somewhat attempting to answer a question.